# Simplifying the result of DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I have a system of differential equations that can be solved with DSolve. However, the coefficients are very long there are like terms which can be combined. I used //FullSimplify in my code but the output of DSolve is still too complicated. Is there a way for Mathematica to turn all the coefficients into decimals and then combine the like terms?

```
Remove["Global'*"];
i = 4;
R2 = 0.001 // Rationalize;
RL = 100000;
RS = 100000000;
R1 = 0.04834 // Rationalize;
C1 = 8.48 // Rationalize;
C2 = 3.44 // Rationalize;
s = DSolve[{V1[t] == RS/(RS + R1)*V2[t] + RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), 
    V2'[t] == 
     1/C1*(i R2 RL RS - (R2 RL + R1 (R2 + RL) + (R2 + RL) RS) V2[t] + 
         RL (R1 + RS) V3[t])/(R2 RL (R1 + RS)), 
    V3'[t] == 1/C2*(V2[t] - V3[t])/R2, V2[0] == 0, 
    V1[0] == RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), V3[0] == 0}, {V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]}, 
   t] // FullSimplify

Plot[Evaluate[{V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Green, Thick}, {Red, 
    AbsoluteDashing[{10, 10}]}}, PlotLegends -> {V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]}]
```

Comment: `s // N // Simplify` or `Simplify@N@s` or `Simplify[N[s]]`.

Comment: I tried added these to my code but then there are some errors. I don't think i'm using these commands right. What does s and N stand for or do i just directly copy and paste them into my code?

Comment: `s` is the name you gave to the output of `DSolve`. You can look up `N` in the MMA help files (which you should be in the habit of doing). So `s // N // Simplify` is a command you would add to the code on the line after the definition of `s` (and you should remove the `FullSimplify`).

Answer (score 4):

```
i = 4;
R2 = 0.001 // Rationalize;
RL = 100000;
RS = 100000000;
R1 = 0.04834 // Rationalize;
C1 = 8.48 // Rationalize;
C2 = 3.44 // Rationalize;

s = DSolve[{V1[t] == RS/(RS + R1)*V2[t] + RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), 
     V2'[t] == 
      1/C1*(i R2 RL RS - (R2 RL + R1 (R2 + RL) + (R2 + RL) RS) V2[t] +
           RL (R1 + RS) V3[t])/(R2 RL (R1 + RS)), 
     V3'[t] == 1/C2*(V2[t] - V3[t])/R2, V2[0] == 0, 
     V1[0] == RS*R1*i/(RS + R1), V3[0] == 0}, {V1[t], V2[t], V3[t]}, 
    t] // FullSimplify;

(s[[1]] // Expand) /. n_?NumberQ :> N[n]

(*  {V1[t] -> 399601. - 0.000333138 E^(-408.622 t) - 399600. E^(-8.39765*10^-7 t),  
     V2[t] -> 399600. - 0.000333138 E^(-408.622 t) - 399600. E^(-8.39765*10^-7 t),   
     V3[t] -> 399600. + 0.000821224 E^(-408.622 t) - 399600. E^(-8.39765*10^-7 t)}
*)
```

EDIT: Note that the [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) [`?NumberQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberQ.html) is used rather than [`?NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) to avoid converting the constant [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html) to its numerical value.

Comment: wow the addition of that line works wonderfully. Can you explain what is actually going on in it though? I've never seen most of those commands before.

Comment: @jerry - see EDIT. In general, highlight unknown commands or operators and press `F1` for help (documentation).

Comment: ahh okok ill play around with that then